# Visual studio error when launch Xamarin app on phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I trying to launch empty blank template cross-platform xamarin.forms app on phone, visual studio throw this error:

*resource directory '~\Test\Test\Test.Android\obj\Debug\81\lp\20\jl\res' does not exist Test.Android*

output:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1703,2): error APT0000: resource directory '~\Test\Test\Test.Android\obj\Debug\81\lp\20\jl\res' does not exist*

Tell me please way to fix it.

Comment: Is the error thrown during build? During device deployment? Is it a dialog box that shows the error, or is it a text based error in some output window? First suggestion would be to delete the bin and obj folders in the Android project folder, and clean and rebuild the app.

Comment: Did you try cleaning building the app once? –

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT, yes, this error thrown during build i do actions which you have adviced me, but result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be due to some corrupted or outdate nuget packages or other cached data.

Try deleting a Xamarin folder that has some cached data. Open the following folder in File Explorer: **`%LOCALAPPDATA%`** (which is a shortcut for **`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local`**)
and delete the **Xamarin** folder.

I would also suggest deleting the all of the Xamarin.Android.* nuget packages  in the packages cache. So open the **`%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\`** folder and delete all of the **Xamarin.Android.*** folders.

The next build might take some time but hopefully will now work.